# How can I glance the HEAD file in SVN repository without updating file?

Tags: svn

How can I glance a HEAD revision source code of a file in SVN repository without updating file?

I often want to glance a HEAD revision source code of a file in `VI` or `cat` command. but I don't want to update the file.(if I update the file, I have to re-update with `svn up -r [revNo]`. )

is they any way to do this?

`svn diff`  doesn't show the whole source code of a file.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `svn cat`:

```
$ svn cat file -rHEAD
```

Gives you the HEAD revision. [More info.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html)